# Django Follow One-To-Many Relationships

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, join

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to follow multiple levels of relationships using Django. Obviously I can use `for` loops, but I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do it (possibly resorting to raw SQL). The model is roughly:

`Subject -> Course -> Module -> Question`

They're linked through Foreign keys (For instance the `Question` module has a Foreign Key pointing to a `Module`).

The following works, but is quite slow and certainly not ideal:

```python
subject = "Mathematics"
courses = Subject.objects.get(name__iexact=subject).course_set.all()
avg_scores = []
for course in courses:
    modules = course.module_set.all()
    for module in modules:
        questions = module.question_set.all().filter(num_attempts__gt=20).filter(avg_score__gt=0).exclude(avg_score__isnull=True).order_by('avg_score')
        for question in questions:
            avg_scores.append(question)
```

I can do this with SQL using the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM question
INNER JOIN module
ON question.module_id=module.id
INNER JOIN course
ON module.course_id=course.id
INNER JOIN subject
ON course.subject_id = subject.id
WHERE subject.name="Mathematics"
AND num_attempts > 20
AND avg_score > 0
```

Is there a way to have something like:

```python
avg_scores = Subject.objects.get(name__iexact="Mathematics").course_set.module_set.question_set.filter(num_attempts__gt=20).filter(avg_score__gt=0).exclude(avg_score__isnull=True).order_by('avg_score')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SQL query would start `SELECT * FROM Model ...` then your Django query should generally start `Model.objects.filter(...)`. So in this case you need something like:

```
Question.objects.filter(module__course__subject__name = 'Mathematics',
                        num_attempts__gt = 20,
                        avg_score__gt = 0).order_by('avg_score')
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't looking in the right area of the doc's I guess. For future readers, the docs are:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

This is WAY faster than `for` loops for the obvious reasons :-)